# Does this characterisation of homeomorphism hold?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, universal-property

Given two topological spaces $X_1, X_2$, I am looking for a characterisation of homeomorphism that works something like this:

$$ X_1 \simeq X_2 \iff \forall Y \text{ topological space } \mathcal{C}(X_1,Y) \simeq \mathcal{C}(X_2,Y) $$

where the first $\simeq$ is of course a homeomorphism, while the second $\simeq$ is some sort of isomophism yet to be (if possible) defined.

I was wondering if this statement could be also taken:

$$ X_1 \simeq X_2 \iff \mathcal{C}(X_1,X_2) \simeq \mathcal{C}(X_2,X_1) $$

Comment: Of course $\mathcal{C}$ means "continuous functions". I guess it may be convenient to think of it as a function  $\mathcal{C}:\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{T}$ where $\mathbb{T}$ is the category of topological spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is spot on: this is [Yoneda's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma). If $\mathsf{C}$ is some (locally small) category, the lemma states that $x \simeq y$ precisely if $\hom(x,-)$ and $\hom(y,-)$ are naturally isomorphic functors. Moreover, all such natural isomorphisms arise as postcomposition of some arrow.

There is a lot of terminology to unpack, but applying this to spaces gives that if $\mathcal{C}(X_1,Y) \simeq \mathcal{C}(X_2,Y)$ *naturally* (in the category-theoretical sense) in $Y$, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks! What about my second intuition?

Comment: Moreover: the homeomorphism relation seems to be intended to do precisely that. However, it looks that it's been proven only in the category theory setting, which has come later than the full topology development. How is it so?

Comment: Note that the underlying condition that makes all this work is *naturality*. Category theory was invented precisely to give that word a formal sense.

Comment: One more thing: the $\simeq$ is a homeomorphism, where $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is endowed with the standard topology (don't even know if there is one)?

Comment: Your second intuition seems false to me, but I haven't come up with a counter-example yet.

Comment: No, there is no need for the $\simeq$ to be a homeo, the isomorphism is as *functors* (which is a category theoretical notion)

Comment: If it's an iso functor, but not a homeo, it means that $\mathcal {C}(X,Y)$ does not belong to the category $\mathbb{T}$. Is this the case?

Comment: Indeed, the set $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ can be endowed with different topologies (for example, as a subspace of the product $Y^X$ or with the compact open topology, with suitable hypotheses) and one can consider the case in which these maps are homeo, but we are only looking at it as a set.

Comment: So you're thinking of $\mathcal{C}$ as $\mathcal{C}:\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{Set}$ and therefore the second $\simeq$ is just a bijection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119247/discussion-between-guidoar-and-roddik).

Comment: (I'm thinking that this resembles some "categorical distribution theory" as we're testing $X_1$ and $X_2$ against "test topological spaces $Y$". If so, this is pretty cool.)

Comment: Yes, that is one way of thinking about this! There was a post on this site quoting Ravi Vakil on a similar interpretation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3184/philosophical-meaning-of-the-yoneda-lemma)